# FB Like button giving error when clicked

Tags: facebook, wordpress, shopp

I'm using the Shopp e-commerce plugin for Wordpress.  I added the Open Graph Helper plugin to help automatically generate FB like buttons on each of the individual product pages that passes the product info to FB rather than generic site info (since the product page is a template).

When I click like I get an error saying that "The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users." even though I've added my admin ID. Page content doesn't populate the comment box, but it does post to the user's FB page correctly.

You can view an example here: http://kranedesign.com/shop/emory-in-dark-olive-with-shearling-lined-hood/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is but when I was creating like button generating code for this site [Sunwise Sunglasses](http://sunwise.co.uk/products/category/polafusion) I found that the order of the the OG tags mattered, and that the Facebook Debugger page was excellent and found any problems: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

There is a [free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shopp-facebook-like-button-sflb/) you can use for Shopp and Facebook like.